# heroku http not redirecting to ssl

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm almost there with my domain setup for heroku and ssl.

The ssl is working, I have setup http://domain.com to redirect to https://www.domain.com, and this is excellent. But the problem lies when you type in https://domain.com - it just times out on heroku. Any pointers on what i am doing wrong?

Maybe displaying it this way would be clearer

http://domain.com works (redirects to https://www.domain.com/)

https://domain.com fails

https://www.domain.com (redirects to https://www.domain.com/ )

http://www.domain.com (redirects to https://www.domain.com/ )

**edit**

i found this is a limitation of namecheap as they do not redirect ssl traffic on the naked domain

Answer (score 2):

i found this is a limitation of namecheap as they do not redirect ssl traffic on the naked domain